# Is there a way to get create a php varialble from ajax data returned from another php script

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a php script that creates a webpage with my select box options

Eg index.php  has a html select box:

```
<select id="sel_option">
   <option value="0">- Select Option -</option> ....
```

this is posted on sel_option change using ajax to a php processing script as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#sel_option").change(function(){
                var optionid = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'procscript.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {option:optionid},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response){ ...
```

I would like to pull some of the returned array into Php variables again in order to change  some of the tabulator group or format options

```
eg  $("#table1").tabulator({
        height:500 ,
        VirtualDomHoz:true,
       <? echo  "groupBy:[\"group_option_from_response array\"]," ?>
```

So Php script1 sends option data by ajax -> php script2 which gathers data from a mysql db and returns to script1

I have tried creating session variables in php script 2 and it works on first selection , but after that it seems to cache the initial sessions in the browser , the response sessions from the second php script do not seem to copy over to the first script in subsequent calls. I think it might because the first page never reloads , all selections are done within the loaded first page using js??

If what I am trying to do is if not possible by php  can I rewrite the php section in tabulator below using some js code?

```
$("#table1").tabulator({
        height:500 ,
        VirtualDomHoz:true,
       <? echo  "groupBy:[\"group_option_from_response array\"]," ?>
        placeholder:"No Data Set",
        columns:[
        {title:"ID", field:"ID",width:30},
         {title:"F_name", field:"f_name", sorter:"string"},
<? echo "{title:\"different var\", field:\"field2\", sorter:"string"},"; ?>
```

Thanks for looking !
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Receive your data through ajax, then create the tabulator object. If there is data coming through ajax for that object, you can add it in, then instantiate it.

```
success:function(response){ ...
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  createTabulator(response,"table1")

});

function createTabulator(data, idToUse) {
  var tabobject = {
    height:500 ,
    VirtualDomHoz:true,
    placeholder:"No Data Set"
  }

  if (data.groupBy) {
     tabobject.groupBy = [data.groupBy]
  }

  var cols = [
   {title:"ID", field:"ID",width:30},
   {title:"F_name", field:"f_name", sorter:"string"}
  ]

 // if there is columns data coming in, bring it as an array...
  data.columns.forEach(item => {
  cols.push({title: item.title, field: item.field, sorter:"string"})
  })

  tabobject.columns = cols;

  $("#"+idToUse).tabulator(tabobject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks John , that looks exactly what I need. My js is really rusty but I can see what you are doing there.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to achieve what you want. I think the best way is just to push the variable to the ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
        option:optionid,
        groupoption: "groupoptionvalue"
    }
    ...
});
```

The first time you just have to send it empty. PHP will always be able to handle the value since you will always capture it at the very beginning.

If your variable is an object or an array, just use JSON.parse/JSON.stringify in javascript and json_encode/json_decode in PHP for them to communicate.

Comment: Interesting Anibal, that allows me to do one side of the process more efficiently.